# what does one sacrifice with this pimpl alternative?

Tags: c++

I have, unfortunately, used `Qt` a lot (it purports to be many things that it is not) and since `Qt` uses the pimpl idiom extensively, I've gotten a lot of experience with the pimpl pattern as well and learned I don't like it. One alternative I like to use is:

```
// .hpp file

struct A
{
private:
  struct B;
  int a{};
};

// .cpp file
struct A::B
{
  // replaces a private member function
  static void f(A& a)
  {
    ++a.a;
  }
};
```

But what is sacrificed using this approach instead of using private function members or pimpl? Performance, binary compatibility? With pimpl, we know that it is performance, because of 1 level of added indirection.

Comment: "I dislike Qt. Qt uses PImpl. Therefore, I dislike Pimpl." is not a valid argument.

Comment: You need to create an instance of `A::B` to do anything useful with it. Where do you do that?

Comment: This doesn't provide behavior to class `A`, therefore it isn't a pimpl alternative in any sense.

Comment: It might be, since using Qt means having to wade through thousands of lines of its code.

Comment: @user1095108: Then is your argument "After reading thousands of lines of pimpl-using Qt code, I've come to hate pimpl"?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you can edit my question if you think it appropriate.

Comment: @user1095108: Is that accurate?

Comment: @user1095108: There's a performance penalty to pimpl. It's not necessarily measurable or significant in all cases, but it's there.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't really understand why you think this is not an alternative to pimpl? Again, `f` is `static`, you don't need an instance of `B` to make a call to `f`.

Comment: @user1095108: Your method only replaces/hides private methods. The pimpl idiom is about hiding private data (non-static).

Comment: @sth True, but pimpl is often (mis)used in situations where only the private methods are hidden and not data. The idea is to use private variables of `A` in static methods of `B`, when you need to hide data as well -  the data is hidden, since the variables are private.

Comment: If you ask me, the entire idea of pimpl is misguided: If a member should be private, it should just be private. And if there are restrictions to when and how it can be modified, a comment on that member should stop people from doing bad things. If people insist on doing bad stuff to your members, pimpl won't stop them.

Comment: @user1095108: If you use private variables on `A`, why not just also use private methods instead of a nested class?

Comment: @sth In my case, to unclutter the interface (and private member functions supposedly _are_ a part of the interface - you can call them , if you are a friend, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one - this won't work if `struct B` needs to be a class `template` that takes arbitrary type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of pimpl is to store data in each instance of `A` without making the internal structure of that data part of `A`'s public interface.

Your code doesn't do that, so it doesn't replace pimpl.

In short, your code is a way to hide helper functions which are implementation details.  pimpl does that and ALSO hides helper data which are implementation details.

Comment: but `B` can operate on members of `A` and members can be private, therefore not a part of the public interface.

Comment: @user1095108: I don't see any members of A to operate on.  Add some, and you'll see how different this is from pimpl.

Comment: @user1095108: An `int`?  Really?  No wonder you don't like pimpl, you don't have even the slightest understand of when it should be used.

Comment: So, what's wrong in having a single `int` member? I am not supposed to write a lot of code.

Comment: @user1095108: Think about when the member is a template STL container using a custom pool allocator and storing another complex type.  Now you need at least 3 extra header files in `A.hpp`, one for the container, one for the allocator, one for the element type.  And all consumers of A get rebuilt if any of those change.  With pimpl, those headers are used only by the implementation of A.

Comment: Yeah, but how often does that happen? I mean, how often do people edit their STL implementation? I'd bet many don't.

Comment: @user1095108: How often do people change from one container to another?  That will also trigger "recompile the whole world" if pimpl isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

If `A::B` only contains static methods/data, there is no point in exposing that at all in the header. You can much simpler only implement those function in the `.cpp` file, without making them part of to the class.

```
// .hpp file

struct A
{
};

// .cpp file
void f(A& a)
{
  // some function
  // Might be called from the implementation of methods of `A`
}
```

So there is not really a reason to have a nested class in the first place.

On the other hand, if you *do* have non-static data/... in `A::B` that needs to be associated with instances of `A` (the situation where the pimpl idiom is used), then you somehow need to associate a `A::B` instance with every instance of `A`.

A straight forward way to do this would be to save a pointer to a `A::B` in each `A`. This is the pimpl idiom.

Comment: Your forget, as a nested class, B is a "friend" of A. It can access all private/protected members. But not, if you declare it outside of A.